# How can I roundup the number in this special kind of situation in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to figure out how to roundup.
Exmaple:

```
3.1049 -> 3.11
```

how can I roundup this?
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
num = 3.1049
print (round(a, 2))
>>> 3.1
```

but I want:

```
>>>3.11     #as 3.1049-> 3.105->3.11
```

Comment: It doesnt roundup from 9, but 4... I want to roundup from 9.

Comment: what do you mean from 9? the 9 is the 4th decimal place, so rounding would be with 3 decimal places, which would be 3.105.

Comment: What code do you have thus far? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: I meant if I roundup 9, then it's 3.105. and I want this number to be 3.11!

Comment: please help me guys... haha

Comment: it doesn't really make any sense. `3.1049` is closer to `3.10` than to `3.11`. Even if you actually do get the value that you want, it will be confusing and a big source of potential errors.

Comment: also, what is the general rule? where do you draw the line? at `.00444444444...5` ? (in which case, just add `.0005555555555...5` and round as usual)

Comment: @Kristine. `0.0049 * 2` is `0.0098`, which is obviously less than `0.01`. So it makes no sense to "round up" `3.1049` to `3.11`.

Comment: in Math `0.6`-`0.9` is rounded up to `1.0` but `0.0`-`0.5` is rounded down to `0.0` -  you have `3.1049` with `9` at the end so it is rounded up to `3.105` and now you have `5` at the end so it is rounded down to `3.10`

Comment: @furas. That is not right, because `3.1051` with `1` at the end also rounds to `3.105` - but `round(3.1051, 2)` is `3.11`, not `3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go dude, it's pretty simple to read and doesn't require any new libraries:

```
num = 3.1049
print(%.2f" % num)
```

This will give you the results of:

```
>>> num = 3.1049
>>> print(%.2f" % num)
>>> 3.10

>>> num = 3.1051
>>> print(%.2f" % num)
>>> 3.11
```

So we can create a method from this with it looking like:

```
>>> def round_hundredths(num): 
        return "%.2f" % num

>>> print(round_hundredths(3.1049))
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> 3.10
```

Hope you understand what's going on here!

Answer (score 0):

I think the math module might work for your situation.

```
import math
num = 3.1049
print(math.ceil(num*100)/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP wants to round up. Probably a general solution. Gumboy's solution works. Here is a general solution.

```
def mround(x, n):
    x_str = str(x).split('.')

    for i in range(len(x_str[1]), n, -1):
        s = 5 * 10 ** -i
        if xs[1][-i + 1] == '0':
            x = round(x, i - 1)
        else:
            x = round(x + s, i - 1)

    return x
```

Usage:

```
>>> mround(3.1049, 2)
3.11
>>> mround(3.1049, 1)
3.1
```

It uses a loop that rounds up per decimal place.

Comment: Why does `mround(3.1049, 1)` give `3.2` !?

Comment: @ekhumoro fixed

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure out how to do this as well and came up with this solution:

```
>if round(x)<x:
>>x=round(x)+1
>else:
>>x=round(x)
```

works for any number. can round to any decimal by specifying round(x,#)